# Dynamic Javascript output in templated HTML

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications, referenceerror

I am trying to build a Javascript class which takes some options and returns builds a form.  I would like the submit function to be determined by the options passed to the class.  All of the HTML is output as expected, but I don't think the javascript that is being output is being parsed.  When the HTML renders I get a syntax error -

> "Unexpected token function"

and when I try to submit the form I get a

> Reference error - "{functionName} is not defined."

Here is the class so far:

```
var ClassOptionsForm = function(options) {

  this.options = options

  this.getSubmissionFunction = function() {
    switch (this.options.type) {
      case 'standard':
        return this.standardSubmit;
        break;
      case 'extendable':
        return this.extendableSubmit;
        break;
    }
  }

  this.successHandler = "function (data, form) {\
     $(form).find('.result').text('Success!').css('color', 'green');\
  }"

  this.failureHandler = "function (data, form) { \
     $(form).find('.result').text('Something went wrong.').css('color', 'red');\
  }"

  this.submitFunctionName = this.options.optionName + "Submit";

  this.standardSubmit = "function " + this.options.optionName + "Submit(form) {\
      google.script.run\
        .withSuccessHandler(" + this.successHandler + ")\
        .withFailureHandler(" + this.failureHandler + ")\
        .withUserObject(form)\
        .setUserOption('" + this.options.optionName + "', form)\
  }"

  this.extendableSubmit = "function(this) {\
      // Extendable Form Submit
  }"


  this.buildForm = function() {
    var value = this.options.value;
    return '\
      <script type="text/javascript">\
      ' + this.getSubmissionFunction() + '\
      </script>\
      <h3>' + this.options.formTitle + '</h3>\
      <form id="' + this.options.optionName + '" onsubmit="' + this.submitFunctionName + '(this)">\
        ' + Object.keys(value).reduce(function(list, key) {
          return list + '<input name="' + key + '" value="' + value[key] + '"/>';
        }, '') + '\
        <button type="submit">Save</button>\
      </form>\
    '
  }
}
```

And here is how form render function is called in the HTML file:

```
<?!= GoogleAnalytics().optionsForm.buildForm(); ?>
```

And here is the final HTML output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function UAIDSubmit(form) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function (data, form) {     
           $(form).find('.result').text('Success!').css('color', 'green');
      })
      .withFailureHandler(function (data, form) {      
          $(form).find('.result').text('Something went wrong.').css('color', 'red');
       })
      .withUserObject(form)
      .setUserOption('UAID', form)
  }
</script>
<h3>UAID</h3>
<form id="UAID" onsubmit="UAIDSubmit(this)">
   <input name="id" value="********">
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I am pretty sure that this has something to do with the way that App Script sanitizes HTML, and I know there are a million ways I could accomplish submitting the form without dynamic JS.  I am just trying to keep my code as dry as possible, and also I'm curious. Any workarounds that keep that don't involve doing away with templated JS?

Comment: I don't get how you call ClassOptionsForm methods with GoogleAnalytics(). Also, the class is declared in the .gs script or inside the HTML?

Comment: When you say "{functionName} is not defined.", which is the name of the function? UAIDSubmit or setUserOption?

Comment: The class is declared on the server side, but initiated in the HTML by calling GooglaAnalytics(), which returns an object which includes an instance of ClassOptionsForm stored as the property '.optionsForm'. Yes, it's UAIDSubmit that is not being fired on submit.

Comment: Can you send me the documentation about "GoogleAnalytics()" ? I haven't found anything on google about how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

When you try to submit the form it won't work because you can use a form object as parameter in a Google Script function but the form object must be the only parameter in that function. Read here[1]

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: You're right! But that's not the my question.  I'm having difficulty getting the submit function (in this case, the UAIDSubmit function) to even start running.